# Is it possible to record video with custom audio on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, video-capture

So, is there any way I could record video but use my own audio for it with iPhone SDK?
Thanks much for all your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible using the new 4.1 apis -- look at AVAssetWriter and AVCaptureSession. AVAssetWriter will allow you to place any inputs, video or audio, to encode into a video.